# I want to recursively list the nodes in xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I recursively want to display xml nodes. But unfortunately it doesn't work. The output is only the first element of the xml file. Why?

```
public string GetOutline(int indentLevel, XmlNode xnod)
{
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        XmlNode xnodWorking;

        result = result.AppendLine(new string('-', indentLevel * 2) + xnod.Name);

        if (xnod.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
        {
            if (xnod.HasChildNodes)
            {
                xnodWorking = xnod.FirstChild;
                while (xnodWorking != null)
                {
                    GetOutline(indentLevel + 1, xnodWorking);
                    xnodWorking = xnodWorking.NextSibling;

                }
            }

        }
        return result.ToString();
}
```

Here the code calling the function. The XML file begins with `<Videos>` then `<Video>`... etc...

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SaveFileDialog fDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        fDialog.Title = "Save XML File";
        fDialog.FileName = "drzewo.xml";
        fDialog.CheckFileExists = false;
        fDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\Piotrek\Desktop";

        if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (var newXmlFile = File.Create(fDialog.FileName));
            {
                string xmlTree = fDialog.FileName.ToString();

                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                xdoc.Load(XML);

                XmlNode xnodDE = xdoc.DocumentElement;

                textBox2.Text = GetOutline(0, xnodDE);

                //StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

                /*
                foreach (var childelement in xdoc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
                    .Select(x => x.Name).Distinct()) 
                {
                   result.Append(childelement + Environment.NewLine );

                }
                textBox2.Text = result.ToString();
                */

                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(xmlTree))
                {
                    sw.Write(textBox2.Text);
                }
            }
}
```

XML content :

```
<Videos>
  <Video>
    <Title>The Distinguished Gentleman</Title>
    <Director>Jonathan Lynn</Director>
    <Actors>
      <Actor>Eddie Murphy</Actor>
      <Actor>Lane Smith</Actor>
      <Actor>Sheryl Lee Ralph</Actor>
      <Actor>Joe Don Baker</Actor>
    </Actors>
    <Length>112 Minutes</Length>
    <Format>DVD</Format>
    <Rating>R</Rating>
  </Video>
  <Video>
    <Title>Her Alibi</Title>
    <Director>Bruce Beresford</Director>
    <Length>94 Mins</Length>
    <Format>DVD</Format>
    <Rating>PG-13</Rating>
  </Video>
</Videos>
```

Comment: Could you show us the code where you initially call `GetOutline`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read all document line by line whith a for each or a while instruction

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(your xml file);
        reader.MoveToContent();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // your code
        }

        reader.Close();
```

not the best way, try to have a look also on linq to xml

Comment: I tried to do that using linq to xml , but I was stuck in recursively get the next Element for XElement (no method for that). I ended up using System.xml :(

Comment: @Peter could you post xml content ?

Comment: XmlException was unhandle. No root element.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything to add the results of the recursive calls to the string you're building.  You need to do this:

```
result.Append(GetOutline(indentLevel + 1, xnodWorking));
```

And this modification should avoid the text nodes and nodes with the same name:

```
public string GetOutline(int indentLevel, XmlNode xnod)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    XmlNode xnodWorking;

    result = result.AppendLine(new string('-', indentLevel * 2) + xnod.Name);

    if (xnod.HasChildNodes)
    {
        List<string> foundElements = new List<string>();
        xnodWorking = xnod.FirstChild;
        while (xnodWorking != null)
        {
            if(xnodworking.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && !foundElements.Contains(xnodworking.Name))
            {
                result.Append(GetOutline(indentLevel + 1, xnodWorking));
                foundElements.Add(xnodworking.Name);
            }
            xnodWorking = xnodWorking.NextSibling;
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: How about the above?  This will prevent child nodes of a particular parent from being repeated and avoid the text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace testStackOverflow
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //Load xml
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");

        //Run query
        var lv1s = from lv1 in xdoc.Descendants("Video")
                   select new
                   {
                       title = lv1.Element("Title").Value
                   };

        //Loop through results
        foreach (var lv1 in lv1s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lv1.title);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```